# Angularjs UI.Bootstrap Pagination customizing template?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I would like to us if there you can point me to a correct sample code for Angularjs UI Bootstrap Pagination to customize the template?

I tried searching google and here in stackoverflow but I cannot find any correct example or explanation on how to use the template-url for pagination for this function component.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

I want to change the cache template "template/pagination/pagination.html" to something like this one

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custompagination.html">
code here...
</script>
```

but it gave me an errors. If you have sample or tips that I can read online, please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to define your custom template in the HTML as follows:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/pagination/pagination.html">
  <div class="pager">
    <div class="page" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{active: page.active, disabled: page.disabled}">{{page.text}}</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and some CSS to style (if required):

```
div.page {
  float:left;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

div.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

You can override a template using the [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) directive. Because this has the same ID as the default Bootstrap pagination template, it will override it. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BgDzE6OIoXRtRGUtDj9M?p=preview) for a demo.