# Angular.ui Pagination Template

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-pagination

I'm using AngularJS and Angular UI Bootstrap and i am trying to costumize the pagination.

On the documentation it is said that I can override the template for the component with a custom provided template.

However i don't know how the html template must be structured. I have tried to use a couple of templates that i found, but none of them quite worked out.

I need the pagination to look a little bit [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PUej.png)

Can someone exemplify how do i need to write this template?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide a link to the mentioned documentation? Also, try to have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133155/1719108).

Comment: Yes, this is the documentaion: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination    And thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is example:

```
  <div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
View <select ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)"><option>3</option><option>5</option><option>10</option><option>20</option><option>30</option><option>40</option><option>50</option></select> records at a time.

    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="2" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    <pre>The selected page no: {{currentPage}}</pre>
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setPage(3)">Set current page to: 3</button>
```

First, I changed in `ui.bootstrap.js` words "previous" and "next" to just for signs `>` and `<`, also i added `style.css`  where I changed colors,
I think my pagination looks similar to your picture.
Here you can see everything, and you can make even more changes if you want:

plunker: 
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/bFMHzgCjVwK4YNPG?preview

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can override the default template by using the `template-url` attribute and providing your custom template

> template-url (Default: uib/template/pagination/pagination.html) - Override the template for the component with a custom provided template

Second, you can find all the templates in the Github page (you can see the default pagination template [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/pagination/pagination.html)). Copy it, change it to your needs and point the templateUrl towards it

Comment: I was looking for the original pagination template link. Thanx for the link